# Unable to retreive image from the firebase storage in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

While fetching i am receiving this error

```
Task <BA25D5D9-E054-4D9D-BB65-2770CFDBEED0>.<2> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/relationships-at-peace.appspot.com/o/images_profile%2FProfile_Image_Of:VgMpm1a3ZaU8kQNXnMhXhhVecdF2?alt=media, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/relationships-at-peace.appspot.com/o/images_profile%2FProfile_Image_Of:VgMpm1a3ZaU8kQNXnMhXhhVecdF2?alt=media, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <BA25D5D9-E054-4D9D-BB65-2770CFDBEED0>.<2>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <BA25D5D9-E054-4D9D-BB65-2770CFDBEED0>.<2>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
```

I dont know why i am getting this error:

This is the snippet i am using to retreive images:

```
func retreiveImagesFromFireBase(downloadUrl:String,imageHolder:UIImageView){
        if downloadUrl != ""{
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadUrl)
            // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
            storageRef.getData(maxSize: 5*1024*1024) { (data, error) in
                if data != nil{
                    if let pic = UIImage(data: data!){
                        imageHolder.image = pic
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try changing the maxSize to something greater, sometimes it retrieves cancelled because its trying to fetch a bigger image